# Gallium OS cannot mount an sd card

Tags: automounting

I'm working on an HP Chromebook kip

When I first installed the sd card, it read as mounted, but I couldn't transfer files to it.

In trying to fix that problem, I managed to unmount it (or so I thought) and that's where I found disappointment.

The current error reads as follows:

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000208-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Any suggestions for fixing the problem, THEN setting it up so I can have permission to access it?

Comment: Did you check it with chkdsk, what was the result? What is the result of ls -la /dev/sd*, who is the owner? Does this card work in other computers? Do other drives work properly in that reader?

Comment: when I run chkdsk it says command not found (I ran both chkdsk and sudo chkdsk - with the same results)

Comment: running ls -la/dev/sd says invalid option

Comment: Can you install that disk utility, then attempt to run it? Did you use the asterisk, and space between -la and /dev/sd*? If that still does not work then find out who owns /path/to/your/disk e.g. /media/username/disk.

Comment: I did not. Sorry I missed the space. Here's what it says:
chrx@chrx:~$ ls -la /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Feb 15 10:48 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Feb 15 10:48 /dev/sda1

Comment: Looks good so far now who owns the disks mount point like in my last comment?

Comment: I reformatted the card to ext4 and got the following:

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-Generic_STORAGE_DEVICE_000000000208-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by who owns the disk mount point.

Comment: I made the incorrect assumption that the mount point might already exist. That does not seem to matter as the newly formated drive still wont mount, hmm... Does this drive work in other computers?

Comment: chrx@chrx:~$ dmesg | tail
[10104.413428] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195333.690:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=30572 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: [10104.799509] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195334.076:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap.cheat.cheat" pid=30595 comm="apparmor_parser"
[10104.799831] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195334.076:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap-update-ns.cheat" pid=30594 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: [10104.800327] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195334.076:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap.cheat.vi" pid=30597 comm="apparmor_parser"
[10104.800689] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195334.077:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap.cheat.nano" pid=30596 comm="apparmor_parser"
[10104.803280] audit: type=1400 audit(1550195334.080:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="snap.cheat.vim" pid=30598 comm="apparmor_parser"

Comment: [10896.911478] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[10896.911483] EXT4-fs (sda1): error loading journal
[11052.240427] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[11052.240434] EXT4-fs (sda1): error loading journal

Comment: I couldn't paste it all at once. Cheers for the help thus far

Comment: No prob. How old is this drive and what was it used for previously, if it is old or had a disk write intensive use case then it is most likely defective? If it is new and it does not work and cant be formated and made to work in a different system, then it is defective. If it is new and can be formated and work correctly in a different system then consider that something is amiss with the formatting binary or the sdcard reader on the non working system.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Then try to reformat the drive if it works great, if not then the drive is likely defective/burnt out *(only if it can not be made to work in a different system as well)*.

Comment: l tried. Permission denied.

Comment: You need to use sudo or to be root with su.

Comment: It worked! AND I can drag and drop files to it. Thank you very much. That's one more problem solved!!

Comment: @user336988 Can you check this as the right answer?